# Error in Laravel with DataTables after adding Google Translator JS code

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am encountering an issue with a Laravel application i got online, after adding the Google Translator JS code to either the `index.php` or the `resources/views` folder, pages with tables are not loading properly. with this error message:

```
DataTables warning: table id=dataTable - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1
```

the Google Translator JS code:

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en'}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

I am looking to integrate Google Translate functionality into my Laravel application using a JavaScript translator script. The goal is to enable users to translate the website content into their preferred language.

Comment: It's very much possible that translating elements on the page translates elements on the page that Datatables uses in it's functionality. One solution is to load the translation JS code after Datatables is done with it's work.
I'm assuming you are using yajra/laravel-datatables to send requests to a PHP API in the backend? You can also inspect the request Datatables sends, and it's response, please up date your question with the contents of those so we have more information to work with.